# How to query the data between two table in this scenario?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three table, I mainly would like to query the transaction

```
User
-----
id

Debit
-----
id
amount
* user_id
create_date

Credit
------
id
amount 
* user_id
create_date
```

So, I would like to get the transaction for particular user that order by the date,  like the following

```
  $150  1  2014-06-15   <== debit
  $200  1  2014-06-16  <===credit
```

The problem is how to query? I need to join debit and credit together? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` not `JOIN` since you want `credit` and `debit` rows separate. *An extra join to table `User` if you want to get columns from it.*

```
SELECT  d.amount, d.create_date, 'debit' transactionType,
        u.user_name
FROM    Debit d
        INNER JOIN User u
            ON d.id = u.user_id
WHERE   u.user_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.amount, c.create_date, 'credit' transactionType,
        u.user_name
FROM    Credit c
        INNER JOIN User u
            ON c.id = u.user_id
WHERE   u.user_id = 1
ORDER   BY create_date
```

Comment: Thanks. yes, how to join if there is a user_name field (in User table) , and I would like to include in the query?